# Round sides of an input box and put in icons?

Tags: css

[image: the desired search bar look]

What rules would I use to round the sides of a text input like in the picture? Also, what is the best way to put in the icons for the search icon and the filter button? The filter button needs to be clickable, but the search icon does not.

Comment: Add code. No code no help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
input {
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

That makes it slightly round. You can set it to 4px for a more conventional look, or a higher number for a more elliptical style.